# Homeomorphism $D^2 \setminus S^1 \to D^2 \setminus S^1$ that cannot be extended to $D^2 \to D^2$

Tags: general-topology

I'm doing this exercise.

[image]

I have trouble proving that $h^{-1}$ is continuous. Also, my guess is that $h$ turns a diameter of $D^2 \setminus S^1$ into a spiral curve. Is this correct? A hint for the proof of non-extendability would be appreciated as well.

Comment: You can explicitly determine a formula for the inverse. Have you done this?

Comment: As for the non-extendability: Note that if $h$ extends to $D^2$, then, in particular, the extension restricts to a continuous map on $D^2_{\varepsilon}:=D^2\setminus \varepsilon D^2$ for any $\varepsilon>0,$ and then $\tilde{h}(re^{it})=h(re^{it})/r$ defines a continuous function on $D^2_{\varepsilon}$. This should give you a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $h^{-1}$ continuous, an easy non-computational method is to show that $h(D_{2}(R))\subset D_{2}(R)$ for all $0<R<1$. Since continuity is a local condition, it's sufficient to prove continuity for all $0<R<1$, but then $h|_{D_{2}(R)}$ is a bijection from a compact space to Hausdorff space so it sends closed set to closed set so for $h^{-1}|_{D_{2}(R)}$ the preimage of closed set is closed.

For non-extendability to a homeomorphism, show that the image of a closed set is not closed. So consider an open radius, which get sent to a spiral, so a closed radius must be sent to a spiral and the entire $S^{1}$ if it were to be closed. But this is true for all radius, contradicting bijectivity.